# Convert a line of text into an int value

Tags: java, string, int

I am making a game that needs a value to seed a random number generator. I want to have it so that you can input text and have it converted into an `long` value to seed `Random()`.

The program runs in the command line and I am assuming that I need to use `Scanner`, which I **can** use.

What I wanted to know is how to turn what `Scanner` gets into a `long` value.

Comment: You may want to use java.util.Scanner class to read input from user.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to add the ascii values for all the characters together and seed with that.

Comment: Are you asking how to convert a string to a long (easy google search), or how to get input from the user (easy google search, but you need to specify if you're talking from the command line, or a GUI app).

Comment: Everyone is not familiar with Minecraft. So please be more specific about what you are trying to do. User will input any text and you want to map that text to an integer value? Or user will simply input integer in text field, or console and you don't know how to convert/read that string to integer?

Comment: The thing about Minecraft was in case anyone knew about it, it would provide more clarity. It was an addition, not a main point.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you just want to generate a seed from any text. Here is a suggestion:

```
    String str = "Sample string";
    long seed = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);               
        seed = seed + (long)ch;
    }

    Random ran = new Random(seed);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `String.hashCode()` method. This is what the Java version of Minecraft does.

**EDIT:** This actually returns an `int` rather than a `long`, but I'll leave it up in case it's helpful to anyone.